# Values not matching in same Grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana, zabbix

I'm facing an inconsistency in Grafana (bound to Zabbix). Screenshot is self explanatory.

Depending on timespan min - max - mean values do not match although panels are duplicate of each others. Only visualization and min-max-mean settings changes; data source is the same. Changing to shorter time span may align values but I haven't found a pattern.

[image: Grafana screenshot]

Any idea?

Comment: It is not self explanatory. It is not clear how query looks like, how aggregation is configured and calculated, raw data from queries are missing,...

Comment: @JanGaraj Source is the same for all panels as created by duplication. No need thus to go to queries as data is the very same..... Proof is that when only changing timespan it happens that values are matching without any other change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to "Max data points" value in query options for that gauge panel which was (far) smaller the the timeline panel. Calculation were limited to less data, hence the difference.